# Owner of the file changed suddenly

Tags: php, macos, symfony

I use symfony2 as both web-application and command-line application

However sometimes after exec command (ex php app/console top:mycommand)

Owner of this file changed to root somehow.

```
.app/cache/dev/jms_diextra/metadata
```

Once the owner is changed, Can't load web-application.

I don't exec command-line application as root either using sudo.

How can I stop changing owner??

Comment: mostly cli and web version of php is running as a different user.

Comment: I checked the cli php. `which php -> usr/local/php5/bin/php`  `-rwxr-xr-x  1 myName  admin  13318508  5 15  2015 /usr/local/php5/bin/php` . `php --version` `PHP 5.6.9 (cli) (built: May 15 2015 13:05:42) ` Then I checked phpinfo.php I am not sure which php I used.  (Does this mean php is included in apache??->) `SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) PHP/5.6.9 `